# Find $f$ given the values of $f'$

Tags: integration, derivatives

In the table below there are the values of $f'(x)$ for $0\leq x\leq10$. I have to analyse the primitive of this function using that table and given that $f(0)=0.1$, create a table of the values of $f(x)$.

[image]

I thought about using the fact that
$$\int_{0}^{x_{0}}f'(x)dx=f(x_{0})-f(0)=f(x_{0})-0.1$$
But I don't know how I can make the values of the table useful.

PS: In the table above, the comma equals to point ($0,421=0.421$)

Comment: There are a lot of numerical integral formulas you can use, e.g. Euler's formula, trapezoid formula, RK method and so on.

Comment: Have a look at the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration

Comment: Yeah, you are going to approximate the integral my discrete sum